# Выражение одного класса через другой

Tags: html5, css3, frontend

Итак, мне нужно чтобы при наведении на один класс другой менял свои аттрибуты. Как реализовать на CSS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если элемент который должен измениться не вложен в тот на который наводится курсор, то остается только JS.

Есть различные хаки с элементами "+" и ">" , но они слишком хрупкие и ненадежные.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#one').hover(
  function(){
    $('#zero').css('color','#fff');
  },
  function(){
    $('#zero').css('color','#000');
  }
)
```

```css
#one:hover{color:yellow}
#one:hover > #one-one{color:pink}
#one:hover + div{color:red}
#one:hover ~ #two > #two-one + div{color:purple}
#one:hover ~ #three{color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <div id="zero">- zero</div>
  <div id="one">
      - hover this
      <div id="one-one">-- one-one</div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
      - two
      <div id="two-one">-- two-one</div>
      <div id="two-two">-- two-two</div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">- three</div>
</div>
```